# Post Method works using https.request but not with Needle or Request libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, node-request

I have nodeApp. It does stuff.

At a particular time I need to communicate with an API that out there in the wild. Using the API in rest tool like Postman is straight forward:

### Postman

```
Url:
https://epicurl

Headers:
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
x-key : secret

Body:
{
"some":"kickass"
"data":"here"
}
```

Sending the above in Postman I get a nice quick response! Yay for rest tools.

So their API works, now I need to make that same response in my Node.js application.

This is where things get odd...

### Request Module: FAILS

```
var request  = require('request')

...lots_of_other_stuff...

var options = {
    uri: 'https://epicURL',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    headers : {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Accept":"application/json",
        "x-key":"secretbro"
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(bodyModel)
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('Body is:');
        console.log(body);
      } else {
        console.log('Error is:');
        logger.info(error);
      }

    cb(body); //Callback sends request back...
});
```

The above fails.. It throws the good'ol ECONNRESET error that we all love! Why? Who knows?

### https.request() - WORKS!

```
var https = require("https");
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';

var headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Accept":"application/json",
    "x-key":"nicetrybro"
}

var options = {
    host: 'www.l33turls.com',
    port:443,
    path: "/sweetpathsofjebus",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');

    var responseString = '';

    res.on('data', function(data) {
        responseString += data;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var resultObject = responseString;

        //Call the callback function to get this response object back to the router.
        cb(resultObject);

    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
req.write(bodyString);
req.end();
```

### But then I notice...

If i leave this line of code in place when using the Request Module it then works...

```
var https = require("https");
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';
```

Is this documented somewhere and I am missing it? Anyone explain this to me?